# Does not get the url from reverse with DRF DefaultRouter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the urls for writing the tests using the reverse function. But I'm getting the error

Errors :-
Reverse for 'notes' not found. 'notes' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from core import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register("notes",views.NoteModelViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("",include(router.urls)),
]
```

and test.py file

```
def test_get_all_notes_path(self):
        url = reverse('notes')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I'm getting error for line  `url = reverse('notes')` that I have mentioned above. My Model and routes everything working fine. Only I'm not get the url in reverse funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whether you set basename or not you can do reverse with `url-path-or-basename`-list

```
url = reverse('notes-list')
```

set the [basename](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) for your router as an option

```
router.register("notes",views.NoteModelViewSet, basename='notes')
```

because basename will create routes with the default name

```
The example above would generate the following URL patterns:

URL pattern: ^notes/$ Name: 'notes-list'
URL pattern: ^notes/{pk}/$ Name: 'notes-detail'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the valuable answer and the documention link. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer, a utility that I found very useful while working with `reverse()` - especially when using third-party nested routers - was [drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions).

After installing it, I use their `show_urls` command like so `python manage.py show_urls`, which lists all of the project's urls with their corresponding viewnames and parameters.

This helped me use `reverse()` in the trickiest nested situations.